# How can I iterate through a range of port numbers, capture the working port and SSH from expect

Tags: bash, expect

currently the below script sample works, however i need to iterate through the port range of 8801 and 8899.  (must be in the expect section, standard bash for loop will not work here).

```
#!/bin/bash
testFunction(){
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh admin@localhost -p 8802
expect "password"

send "password\r"
expect "$ "
interact
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using environment variables. It's quick and dirty but it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
function testFunction {
    local TESTPORT=$1
    expect << EOF
spawn sshpass -f x ssh -p ${TESTPORT} admin@localhost
expect "$ "
send -- "w\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
EOF
}
testFunction 8802
testFunction 8803
```

I also used sshpass instead of having the ssh password in the expect script. I was using this to test the idea. In this case, the file "x" has the password in it (and is set with highly restrictive permissions).

Answer (score -1):

Can you replace that hard coded 8802 in your HERE doc with a variable?  And then you'd be able to put the entire testFunction in a loop, passing in a different port for each iteration.

Comment: Comments should be for posting solutions, not asking questions. Why don't you just show how to replace it with a variable?